# How to display an NSString in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I need to display NString using UITextView.

```
[message setText:str];
```

setText didn't work! I tried NSLog

```
NSLog(@"str %@ :)", str);
```

str prints on console but didn't appear on UITextView!

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Put NSLog for message. check it is not nil.

Comment: Check the outlet connection of UITextView if u r using xib.

Comment: We need more detail, is 'Message' a valid non-nil object. How and where are you using this ? (e.g. publish more code). setText is used to do this, clearly its on your end and we need to see more of your code

Comment: @OMK I put NSLog it not nil! but setText is nil!

Comment: @Sudha UITextView is connected

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin what do you mean by valid non-nil object? message is UITextView object.

Comment: @Mariam 'non-nil' is the opposite of nil. I.e. Is it a valid textfield instance. What else could it possibly mean

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for your problem. If none of the comments (e.g. text color, message nil) do the trick: did you set up your `UITextView` using a storyboard? If so: did you connect the textView to a property?

Comment: UITextView is connected. @tilo

Answer (score 0):

Log the textview.text

```
NSLog(@"message.text %@ :)", message.text);
```

### If (its doesn't return null than ...)

I think issue is with text color.
So either change text Color of UITextView

```
message.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Or change UITextView Background Color

```
message.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

### else


Check that your Textview is connected in xib/storyboard with the viewcontroller. And its have Property and synthesize.

In `ViewController.h` file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *message;
```

In `ViewController.m` file

```
@synthesize message;
```

## UPDATE

Select the message textview in storyboard and check that...
Your utility bar in storyboard looks like this?

[image]

Comment: UITextView is connected and it has property and synthesize. There is no problem with text color because I checked the same NSString on NSLog it displayed but on UITextView it nil!

Comment: Have nsloged the value of textview? Not string? `NSLog(@"message.text %@ :)", message.text);` add this line and check that textview has value or not.

Comment: And how you creating the textview from Xib/Storyboard or Programmatically?

Comment: it has (null) :). I create it from Storyboard.

Comment: So the string is not null. Message is connected. and set text does not work.

Comment: That means you are setting the null text after settext in your code

Comment: Check that message textview data not modified after `[message setText:str];` code

Comment: And probably this is not make difference but try to set text on textview like this `message.text = str;`

Comment: message textview not modified after setText. by the way, I can setText just in one function but in another function I can't! I tried message.text = str; it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you display the setText function and log of str?

Comment: And if possible than screenshot of simulator